# Why adding numbers in a javaScript object sorts it by default?

Tags: javascript, object, hashmap

Recently I cam across an interesting scenario while working with javaScript objects.

If we add any strings in an object it gets saved in the order that we added them

```
let obj = {};
obj[“z”] = true;
obj[“a”] = true;
obj[“c”] = true;

console.log(Object.keys(obj)) // [“z”,”a”,”c”]
```

But in the case of adding numbers, it seems to sort it by default

```
let obj = {};
obj[9] = true;
obj[1] = true;
obj[5] = true;

console.log(Object.keys(obj)) // [1,5,9]
```

What is the reason that this is happening???

Comment: Here is a chapter describing how it was implemented: https://exploringjs.com/es6/ch_oop-besides-classes.html#_traversal-order-of-properties "First, the string keys that are integer indices (what these are is explained in the next section), in ascending numeric order.". As for why, no clue!

Comment: Also, take a look at this answer in regards to ES2015 - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5525795/does-javascript-guarantee-object-property-order/38218582#38218582

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Does JavaScript Guarantee Object Property Order?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5525795/does-javascript-guarantee-object-property-order)